# TypedActors in akka 2.6

Tags: java, akka, typedactor

How am I supposed to use the new akka.actor.typed API instead of the deprecated TypedActor in akka 2.6? There is no word in docs about that.

With akka 2.5 I'm using `TypedActor`s to interact with external libraries.
This is done by implementing some interface with a `TypedActor` and then pass it to the corresponding external library listener. In akka 2.6 this `TypedActor` is deprecated stating to use the new `akka.actor.typed` API.
Unfortunately I can not find a way to do the same here (implement the interface within an actor). Any suggestions here? Examples are most welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct 1:1 counterpart of `TypedActor`, to do the same you will have to manually implement such adapter interfaces to do the messaging for you.

You can read some of the motivation here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/project/migration-guide-2.5.x-2.6.x.html#typedactor